# Need suggestions for designing a content organizer

Tags: python, tagging, saving-data

I am trying to write a python program which could take content and categorize it based on the tags. I am using Nepomuk to tag files and PyQt for GUI. The problem is, I am unable to decide how to save the content. Right now, I am saving each entry individually to a text file in a folder. When I need to read the contents, I am telling the program to get all the files in that foder and then perform read operation on each file. Since the number of files is less now (less than 20), this approach is decent enough. But I am worried that when the file count increase, this method would become inefficient. Is there any other method to save content efficiently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sounds like you could use a database like:
http://buzhug.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I would have used a database, but my idea is to make it work with mere python. If I save the content in files, I could perform a simple read operation on the file and get the content. I might have to share the content and it will be better if the data is stored in files instead of a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module from stdlib. Data will be stored in a single file. The code might be even simpler than the one used for reading all adhoc text files by hand.

You could always export the data in a format suitable for sharing in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about this module earlier. Solved my problem.